# populate an HTML <ul> with images from a folder automatically

Tags: php, html

I wanted to ask how can I populate an HTML list with Images located in a folder automatically?

lets say I have 4 pages with 4 different lists.
lets say the lists are as follows: Cars, Motorcycles, Airplanes, Ships
each list entry has a src as a thumbnail and a href as a link to full size image.
my folder contain images with specific titles:
C=Cars
M=Motorcycles
A=Airplanes
S=Ships

then I have a serial number

and the ending is either
T=Thumbnail
F=Full Image

so a complete file name would be C20T.jpg or C20F.jpg.

I am looking for a script that will update the 4 lists according to their subject and populate them automatically with related file names.

from my search here I have found this piece of code but I believe it needs some tweaking and I am not sure how to do this :(

```
$dir    = '/images';
$files = scandir($dir);
$images = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
  if(fnmatch('*.jpg',$file)) {
    $images[] = $file;
  }
}

foreach($images as $image) {
  echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'" />';
}
```

I hope someone could help me with this!

Thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$type = 'c';

$imagesDir = 'images/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . $type . '*[TYPE].{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

This should get all your full images.

Making a `ul` is then pretty easy...

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo str_replace('[TYPE]', 'F', $image); ?>"><img src="<?php echo str_replace('[TYPE]', 'T', $image); ?></a>" alt="" /></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Alex! I wanted to ask though where do I place the first bit of code? The one with the variables I believe

Comment: @Jake Place it anywhere above where you output the HTML - make sure the HTML generating can access `$images` from its scope (or adjust if necessary).

Comment: OK Thanks! Also not very related to this topic I wanted to ask if you know that Facebook "Like" feature? Is it possible to add a like button per list item?

Comment: @Jake I am not too sure, you may need to ask a new question about that here :)